# Intellisense warning "Expression is always false" after modulo operation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, modulo

Consider this simple method that should round up a value to the next multiple of `align`:

```cs
        private long RoundUp(long offset, long align)
        {
            long evenBy = offset % align;
            if (evenBy == 0) // This line is underlined and Visual Studio means "Expression is always false"
            {
                return offset;
            }

            offset += (align - evenBy);

            return offset;
        }
```

The `if` statement is underlined and Visual Studio (2022) claims that the expression is always false. I can confirm with the debugger that both cases are followed in this test method:

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void TestRounding()
        {
            Assert.Equal(1024, RoundUp(1024, 1024));
            Assert.Equal(1024, RoundUp(100, 1024));
        }
```

What is the cause for this warning?

**Edit:**
Here's a screenshot. No error code is given, unfortunately.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If it helps, my VS2022 doesn't show this.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fONY7.jpg - can you post a representative project we can load, in case it's a setting/project specific peculiarity somewhere? What is the error code?

Comment: I agree, there is no warning for me either. (also VS2022)

Comment: @CaiusJard There's no error code, just the underlining and a popup. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: I'll first try to check whether updating VS helps. I'm not at the latest version right now.

Comment: And there is nothing in the Errors/Warnings/Info panel (sometimes eg Info is toggled off)? I was asking about the code to see what extension is generating it.. Do you use Resharper? (I don't)

Comment: @CaiusJard No, there was nothing in the errors panel under warnings or errors. And when building, there's no error or warning, either. After updating everything, I have now some other problem to solve first. I'll report back.

Comment: @CaiusJard Updating didn't help. I _am_ using Resharper and the warning seems to come from it. Really appears to be a bug there, as the warning goes away when I change the data type to int.

Comment: Worth reaching out to JetBrains? I'm sure they'd be interested n false positives. Also, does it still report as always false if you compare with a long constant `0L`?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I'll be writing a report. And no, changing the constant to long doesn't make a difference. I assume there's something wrong in what they think is the result of a modulus operation.

Comment: Does it only complain for comparison with 0?

Comment: @CaiusJard No, it complains with the same message (still "expression is always _false_") when I change to a different constant. The message goes away if compared with a variable.

Comment: That does indeed sound like a bug!